# How to make a list of json objects?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm using asp.net mvc2 and trying to send a list of json objects with hard coded values from the home controller, and receive them in index....
in the code below i'm sending 1 json object ....
how do i send many?

in home controller:

```
public ActionResult JsonValue()
        { 
            var result = new 
            { 
                pID = 1, 
                pName = "Lina",
                pStart = "",
                pEnd = "",
                pColor = "ff0000",
                pLink = "",
                pMile = 0,
                pRes = "Brian",
                pComp = 0,
                pGroup = 1,
                pParent = 0,
                pOpen = 1
            };


            return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

and receiving it in index like this:

```
        var Jid = null;
        var Jname = null;
        var Jstart = null;
        var Jend = null;
        var Jcolor = null;
        var Jlink = null;
        var Jmile = null;
        var Jres = null;
        var Jcomp = null;
        var Jgroup = null;
        var Jparent = null;
        var Jopen = null;
        var Jtitle = null;
        var g = new JSGantt.GanttChart('g', document.getElementById('GanttChartDIV'), 'day');
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.getJSON('../../Home/JsonValue', function (data) {
                Jid = data.pID;
                Jname = data.pName;
                Jstart = data.pStart;
                Jend = data.pEnd;
                Jcolor = data.pColor;
                Jlink = data.pLink;
                Jmile = data.pMile;
                Jres = data.pRes;
                Jcomp = data.pComp;
                Jgroup = data.pGroup;
                Jparent = data.pParent;
                Jopen = data.pOpen;
                Jtitle = '|id= ' + Jid + '|Name: ' + Jname + '|Start: ' + Jstart + '|End: ' + Jend;

            }); // end $.getJSON
```

thanks a million in advance...
Lina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add them to an array and return that (via the JSON call of course).

personally I would make a class rather than the anonymous object you have and then add to a generic list, once you have the list filled you can pass the list.ToArray() into the Json call. I havent tried but you may be able to pass the list direct to the Json (I am unsure if it will create a Json array from a generic list).

edit,

It looks like Json will turn any enumerable into a Json array so I would say you can pass the list generic list in, I will add some code later

code added below.

I dont for one minute think you should code a `List<object>` personally, as explained I would create a class for your anonymous object so you  can strongly type it. hopefully this will give you the idea though

```
public ActionResult JsonValue()
        {
            List<object> jsonlist = new List<object>();
            jsonlist.Add(new
            {
                pID = 1,
                pName = "Lina",
                pStart = "",
                pEnd = "",
                pColor = "ff0000",
                pLink = "",
                pMile = 0,
                pRes = "Brian",
                pComp = 0,
                pGroup = 1,
                pParent = 0,
                pOpen = 1
            });

            jsonlist.Add(new
            {
                pID = 1,
                pName = "Lina",
                pStart = "",
                pEnd = "",
                pColor = "ff0000",
                pLink = "",
                pMile = 0,
                pRes = "Brian",
                pComp = 0,
                pGroup = 1,
                pParent = 0,
                pOpen = 1
            });

            return Json(jsonlist,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```